# PHP/html: instant search function: Can't search for foreign (e.g.Chinese) characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I built a instant search application for my webpage(similar to google search).It works perfect with english characters but not for foreign character(tested with Chinese) I wondered how to modify to make it able to  search with foreign characters.

Below is the setting which I think might be relevant:

Database setting:

Type:varchar(50)
Collation: latin1_swedish_ci

PHP search query:

```
 $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from objects WHERE Match(name) Against ('%$search%' in natural language mode) LIMIT 9") or die("could not search! Oops");
```

Also noted that I have already included the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my html/php file.

Comment: change the collation to `utf8_general_ci`

Comment: Thx with hug. it works now.

Comment: np. glad i helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Place below statement just above your actual query to support UTF characters.

```
mysqli_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
```

So you query should be like below:

```
mysqli_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from objects WHERE Match(name) Against ('%$search%' in natural language mode) LIMIT 9") or die("could not search! Oops");
```